# How to force an (inline) Telegram bot ask for location permission again?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot setup with /setinlinegeo which asks users for permission to get gps location. It works but telegram only asks for this permission once and keep this answer forever. If a user decides to change his/her mind and want to stop (or allow) the bot's get-location, he/she can't find the option to disable/enable it. On backend (server-side), I also don't have anyway to force the bot to ask again or flush the users previous permission.

So instead of creating a new inline bot, what can I do to solve this issue?

Reference about Telegram inline bots with location based-results: https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline#location-based-results

Comment: You can only create new bot to do this for now :(

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the user setting by Disable and Re-Enable inline location request via @BotFather

1. /setinlinegeo via @BotFather
2. Choose your bot
3. Click Disable button
4. /setinlinegeo via @BotFather again
5. Choose your bot
6. Click Enable button

Telegram will prompt user for location permission again.